# How to stop API feed from disconnecting without showing errors

Tags: python, rest

I have constructed a news feed from a news agency which reads headlines as they're published (I'd rather not say which one for privacy reasons). One of the drawbacks of this API is that, unlike the filtered-stream from the Twitter API, it explicitly says in the documentation for this news agency's API that one needs to continuously fetch individual headlines in order to "simulate a wire feed". Thus, I have constructed a while loop that continuously fetches headlines and prints them to the terminal.

```
import config # The .py file that contains the username and password for my account with this service.

username = config.username
password = config.password

values = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'format':'json'
}

# Functions
# The API requires fetching an authentication token using your username and password, which is regenerated every 24 hours.

def get_token(): 
    token = ''
    parameters = values
    url = '<URL>'
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    token = response.json()['authToken']['authToken'].replace('=', '')
    return token

# The API has multiple possible channels (though my subscription only has access to one),
#so I fetch the available channels using the authentication token obtained by the previous function.

def get_channel():
    token = get_token()
    parameters = {'token': token}
    url = '<URL>'
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    dict_data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
    channel = dict_data['availableChannels']['channelInformation']['alias']
    return channel

def get_headline():
    url = '<URL>'
    channel = get_channel()
    token = get_token()
    values = {'channel':channel, 'token':token, 'limit':1, 'maxAge':'10s'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=values)
    if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception(
                    f"Cannot get stream (Error {response.status_code}): {response.text}"
    dict_data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
    return dict_data

# According to the docs, the only way to simulate an actual live feed is to make constant requests for headlines,
#so I constructed a while loop that fetches headlines and then adds each headline to a set
#and compares each new headline that is fetched with the set to see if it has already been fetched.
#If it has, then the headline is printed.

def api_stream():
    print('Connected to Stream!')
    new_headline = ''
    data = set()
    while True:
        dict_data = get_headline()
        
        try:
# News headlines are classified on a scale of priority from 1-4 (1 being highest priority).
# Since I am only interested in headlines for breaking news, I only headlines of priorities 1, or 2.
            if int(dict_data['results']['result']['priority']) < 3:
                new_headline = dict_data['results']['result']['headline']
            else:
                pass
            if new_headline not in data and new_headline != '':              
                print(new_headline)
                data.add(new_headline)
        except KeyError:
            continue 
# The get_headline() function fetches headlines that are only 10 seconds old, so if the most recent headline is older than it, it will return a KeyError saying that ['result'] is not a key in the dictionary, so I handle the exception this way.
```

This code usually works throughout the day but overnight starting at around midnight until around 7:30am, it will stop printing headlines without displaying an error message. I've tried a number of different things, such as containing this in another while loop, adding a second except block which calls the api_stream() function in the event of an error but nothing's worked, it just stops fetching headlines without warning.